# Ceiling Fan 3 Way Wiring and Removal of Old Light Switch

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan that has a separately wired 3 way light kit. My new ceiling fan powers the light kit, so I don't need the 3 ways for the light so I want to hook the ceiling fan to the 3 way. Then cut the wires from the single switch that previously operated just the old ceiling fan to disable it. I would wire nut the ends of the cut wires with the thought that I would just leave this switch dead.

Does this seem safe and reasonable? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Capping and abandoning the wires in a box is ok, but why not go all the way and disconnect the wires at the switch, cap them and remove the switch and replace with a blank cover.

You will save a new owner from becoming crazy, trying to figure out what the switch operates.

Also, If there is not another way to turn on a light when coming into the room, you will be violating the code that requires that

Comment: That is a great idea. So, just capping them is OK and I will get another cover.